# Why does currying anonymous functions change Haskell's type inference from Num to Integer?

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-inference, currying

I'm running through [A brief introduction to Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/A_brief_introduction_to_Haskell) and have come to the [section on currying](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/A_brief_introduction_to_Haskell#Currying_2).  (So, please correct any errors I've made in terminology.)

This section says:

> Here is a two-argument function defined in our usual manner.
>   
>   `Prelude> let myadd x y = x + y
>   Prelude> myadd 3 4
>   7`

And then a bit further on:

> Here is a third equivalent way to define myadd, as an anonymous function returning another anonymous function.
>   
>   `Prelude> let myadd = \x -> \y -> x + y
>   Prelude> :t myadd
>   myadd :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer`

Even though the it says "equivalent", surprisingly (to a beginner like me) it's not, because the type of `myadd` is more general:

```
Prelude> :t myadd
myadd :: Num a => a -> a -> a
Prelude> myadd 1.5 2.5
4.0
Prelude> myadd3 1.5 2.5

<interactive>:12:8:
    No instance for (Fractional Integer) arising from the literal `1.5'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Integer)
    In the first argument of `myadd3', namely `1.5'
    In the expression: myadd3 1.5 2.5
    In an equation for `it': it = myadd3 1.5 2.5
```

Comment: If I run `:t \x -> \y -> x+y` in ghci, I get `\x -> \y -> x+y :: Num a => a -> a -> a`. Very strange... Seems that this has something to do with `let`...

Comment: It's the "Dreaded Monomorphism Restriction".